# Tika including adjacent hyperlink when parsing text in word document

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-tika

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String fileContent = tika.parseToString(new 
FileInputStream("test.doc"));
System.out.println(fileContent);
```

Input:

The Indian Economic Service was introduced by Prime Minister [Jawaharlal Nehru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jawaharlal_Nehru)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Economic_Service#cite_note-IES_History-2)  for formulating and implementing economic policies and programmes in India.

Output:

The Indian Economic Service was introduced by Prime Minister Jawaharlal Nehru

HYPERLINK "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Economic_Service" \l "cite_note-IES_History-2"
[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Economic_Service#cite_note-IES_History-2)] for formulating and implementing economic policies and programmes in India.

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: 1.14. tried with 1.15 too...no luck